# How to get parameter structure from the WSDL

Tags: java, wsdl

I am trying to parse the WSDL. For parsing I am using javax.wsdl package.

One of the method in the WSDL accepts complex parameter. Is there a way/API through which I can get the structure of the complex parameter.

Snippet from my wsdl:

```
<xsd:element name="PERSONAL_DATA" type="PERSONAL_DATATypeShape"/>
<xsd:complexType name="PERSONAL_DATATypeShape">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="EMPLID" type="EMPLIDTypeShape"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="EMPLIDTypeShape">
<xsd:simpleContent>
<xsd:extension base="EMPLIDTypeDef"/>
</xsd:simpleContent>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:simpleType name="EMPLIDTypeDef">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:maxLength value="11"/>
<xsd:whiteSpace value="preserve"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

At the end, I need to construct the SOAPRequest.For that I need the parameter structure. Is there a way /API through which I can get the structure??

Thanks,
Maviswa

Comment: Isn't that defined in the associated XSD?